# Continue execution of a loop after exception and store all errors in stringbuilder object

Tags: c#

I am reading an excel file and anytime I read a field
that has a wrong value execution is stopped and goes
to the catch section. (example is having a string in a dateTime column)
I want to be able to complete the loop and store all the error
messages I encounter in a stringbuilder object without stopping
execution. I don't want users correcting the input file as they encounter the error. 
The string builder object should show all errors in the file.

How can I achieve this please? I tried continue no luck.

```
public void  testThis()
{
    try
    {
        for (int rowNumber = startRow + 1; rowNumber <= currentWorkSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        // read each row from the start of the data (start row + 1 header row) to the end of the spreadsheet.
        {
            object col1Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value;
            object col2Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value;
            object col3Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value;
            object col4Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value;

            if ((col1Value != null && col2Value != null))
            {
                exampleDataList.Add(new PersonalData
                {
                    firstname = col1Value.ToString(),
                    lastname = col2Value.ToString(),
                    currentDate = col3Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(col3Value),
                    mySalary = col4Value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(col4Value)
                });
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception Exception)
    {
        //continue.. do not stop
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds usefull ... what is the problem your having with the code ?

Comment: Put the `try/catch` *inside* the for loop.

Comment: I also have some other code outside the for loop. Can I still use another outer try catch? I just copied this section for you to see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `Try..Catch` block into the `For` loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int rowNumber = startRow + 1; rowNumber <= currentWorkSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        // read each row from the start of the data (start row + 1 header row) to the end of the spreadsheet.
{

    try
    {

        object col1Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value;
        object col2Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value;
        object col3Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value;
        object col4Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value;

        if ((col1Value != null && col2Value != null))
        {
            exampleDataList.Add(new PersonalData
            {
                firstname = col1Value.ToString(),
                lastname = col2Value.ToString(),
                currentDate = col3Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(col3Value),
                mySalary = col4Value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(col4Value)
            });
        }

    }      
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         //log exception here
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}{2}",rowNumber, e.Message, Environment.NewLine);           
    }
} 

//convert the StringBuilder into the final string object
string allMessages = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you must put the try/catch inside the for, not outside!

then in the catch you can use or not the continue, does not matter!

create the `StringBuilder` istance before entering the for loop and after the for you can display its content with a `.ToString()`